# Django Rest Framework - exclude group from using viewsets

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I would like to restrict the api usage of a certain group to only one view

```
@api_view(['POST])
def get_something(request):
    # let's do something here...
    return Response(...)
```

whereas all ViewSets and ModelViewSets should return a 403 or 405 error.

What is the best practice for doing so?

So far I checked for the `request.user.group`in the class methods e.g.

```
class MyModelViewSet(ModelViewSet):

    ...

    def list(request):
        if restricted_group in request.user.groups.all():
            return Response(status=Http_403)
        else:
            return super(list, ...)
```

Comment: you can try to add a custom permission to the ViewSet https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions

Comment: I would like to avoid this as it requires updating all the existing viewsets